# Do structure members have to be separately allocated when using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures

I am having a bit of a hard time understanding how dynamic memory allocation works together with structures. If I have a structure such as:

```
struct mystruct
{
    char *a;
    int  *b;
    char *c;
};
```

If I allocate memory, dynamically, for a structure, do I also have to allocate memory for the `char*` inside it?

Comment: No, the members of the struct are part of the struct, so if you have an array of 50 `mystruct`s, then each array element will contain the three pointers `a`, `b` and `c`. (Of course that has nothing to do with what the pointers are pointing to.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If one takes your question literally, you already did so:

  If you allocate space to store objects of your `mystruct`-type, you allocate space for *all* members, *even if they are pointers*.
- If one pre-supposes that *you aren't thinking like a programmer* yet, and thus far too sloppy, the answer will probably be no:

  You allocated memory for the pointers, not for them to point to.

  If you think about it, anything else would be really surprising, and neccessitate lots of precognitive and telepathic power on the part of the compiler;
  what should the pointer point at? A 0-terminated string? Which one? A buffer of length `MAGICCONSTANT`? Why not in the middle of one?

Comment: If I am not allocating memory for the pointers to point, could this generate a segmentation fault?And yes I am a beginner, I started learning C just a few months ago.Thanks for your help

Comment: Simply remember never to use uninitialized variables, be they pointers or not. That alone is already undefined behavior. One common kind of UB for indexing/dereferencing uninitialized pointers is certainly a segmentation fault. Don't depend on not getting something more subtle or blatant though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do, when you allocate `memory` for the structure only the space ocuppied by the `a` and `b` pointers is allocated.

For the contents you want the pointers to point to, you need to call `malloc` again, you should do something like

```
struct mystruct *test;

test = malloc(sizeof(*test)); // allocated space for 3 pointers.
if (test != NULL)
{
    test->a = malloc(countOf_As);
    test->b = malloc(countOf_As * sizeof(int));
    test->c = malloc(countOf_Cs);
}
```

if you want to make sure, check `sizeof(struct mystruc)` it will be `3 * sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: And if the structure is allocated statically but its contents are pointers, do I also have to allocate memory for its contents?for example if instead of *test was test[20] would I still have to malloc for test.a, test.b and test.c?

Comment: Yes you do, if you want all the content to be statically allocated you need something like `struct mystruct {char a[SOMESIZE]; int b[SOMESIZE2]; char c[SOMESIZE3];};`

Comment: I would allocate them statically but there seems to be a problem with my compiler/IDE.I have asked this question because I am currently debugging a program which fails due to an error on a line that does something like this: test[i].a=otherstructure[3][4].b;  The compiler says "assignment to expression with array type", only if a and b(which are both char*'s) are statically allocated.So that is kind of confusing for a beginner like me, if you could explain I would be really grateful

Comment: What you mean fails? that seems a valid thing to do, but weather `test[i]` overflows the arrays of struct is impossible to know because you haven't posted enough code, there are many many reasons that could make that line fail so guessing would be wrong, explain `fails` or post the code.